# Disable Android Market localization

Tags: google-play-store, 2.1-eclair, localization

I'm using LG GT540 with (LG) official Android 2.1. The market has never been updated, but months ago, the top apps show my local (Vietnam) apps.

Those top rated are actually very bad, can I disable it, use old international version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your phone is rooted, you can install Market Enabler from Android Market and choose another location. Sometimes you may need to change the language settings on your device.